# Nested forms using form_with not submitting parameters properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following class definition

```
class Globalvalue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :globalnations, inverse_of: :globalvalue  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :globalnations, allow_destroy: true
```

is then applied via a form.  the controller does specify:

```
def globalvalue_params
  params.require(:globalvalue).permit(:name, [..], globalnations_attributes: [:nation_id, :globalvalue_id])

    <% @continents.each do |continent| %>
      <h4><%= continent.name %></h4>
      <% @nations_for_continent = @nations.order(name: :asc).select{ |i| i.continent_id == continent.id } %>
      <% @nations_for_continent.each do |nation| %>
        <%= fields_for :globalnations do |ff| %>
          <%= ff.check_box :nation_id, {}, nation.id %> <%= ff.label nation.name %><br>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Using the above generates HTML as

```
<input name="globalnations[nation_id]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="globalnations[nation_id]" id="globalnations_nation_id" /> <label for="globalnations_Algeria">Algeria</label><br>
```

but the submission is not handled in a nested manner, no values are effectively generated for selected items. The nested attributes are ignored.

```
 Parameters: { "globalvalue"=>{"name"=>"start"}, "globalnations"=>{"nation_id"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"1"}
```

[using the rails form helpers guides syntax](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)

```
<%= form.fields_for :globalnations do |ff| %>
```

the whole `fields_for` block is simply not rendered, not even the `continent.name`

What needs to be corrected in the syntax?

Comment: `<%= form.fields_for :globalnations do |ff| %>` will generate nothing, because you haven't provided block which utilize ff builder. `ff.text_field :field1` and so on

Comment: I thought of that, but then what is wrong with `ff.check_box :nation_id, {}, nation.id` ?

Comment: Your example is not clear. I'm not sure if you're using separate method for view rendering and for form handling